Looping through cells in a column for file names to SaveAs
I am trying to do a loop to save a file with different names located in a column of cells.
The code saves. How to get it to continue going down to "E5"?
Private Sub Save_Click()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "p:"
    FileName = Sheet10.Range("E4").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub



Change the start and end value as needed in For clause

Private Sub Save_Click()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String, i As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "p:"
    For i = 4 To 10 ' modify as needed
        FileName = Sheet10.Range("E" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub


I got an error, specified dimension is not valid.

Pls make sure FileName is a valid file name on Win OS. Which line raises error? What's the error number and text?

Create Code-Free (.xlsx) Copies of the Workbook Containing the Code (ThisWorkbook)

Creates a (macro-enabled) copy of the workbook containing this code using the first name.
Then it saves it as a macro-free (.xlsx) file, deletes the macro-enabled copy, opens the macro-free file and saves copies of it using the remaining names.
Finally, closes the macro-free file leaving the (initial) workbook containing this code intact.

Main
Private Sub Save_Click()
    
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "P:\"
    Const SHOW_MESSAGES As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet10
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ws.Parent ' or 'Set wb = ThisWorkbook'
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("E4", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, cell As Range
    Dim Counter As Long, ErrNumber As Long
    Dim FilePath As String, swbName As String, FileBaseName As String
    Dim IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(cell.Value) Then
            FileBaseName = cell.Value
            If IsFirstFound Then
                FilePath = FOLDER_PATH & FileBaseName & ".xlsx"
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    On Error Resume Next
                        dwb.SaveCopyAs FilePath
                        ErrNumber = Err.Number
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                If ErrNumber = 0 Then  ' successfully saved
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                Else ' an error occurred while saving
                    If SHOW_MESSAGES Then
                        MsgBox "Cannot save as """ & FilePath & """!", _
                            vbExclamation
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Set dwb = RefWorkbookConvertedToXLSX( _
                    swb, FOLDER_PATH, FileBaseName, SHOW_MESSAGES)
                If Not dwb Is Nothing Then
                    IsFirstFound = True
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                End If
            End If
        'Else ' is error or blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If IsFirstFound Then dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox Counter & " cop" & IIf(Counter = 1, "y", "ies") _
        & " of this workbook created.", _
        IIf(Counter = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)
    
End Sub

Help
Function IsNoErrorNoBlank(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If Not IsError(Value) Then
        If Len(Value) > 0 Then IsNoErrorNoBlank = True
    End If
End Function

Function RefWorkbookConvertedToXLSX( _
    wbthis As Workbook, _
    FolderPath As String, _
    NewFileBaseName As String, _
    Optional ShowMessages As Boolean = False) _
As Workbook

    Dim wbName As String: wbName = wbthis.Name
    Dim FileBasePath As String: FileBasePath = FolderPath & NewFileBaseName
    Dim OldFileExtension As String:
    OldFileExtension = Right(wbName, Len(wbName) - InStrRev(wbName, ".") + 1)
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FileBasePath & OldFileExtension
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, ErrNumber As Long
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
            wbthis.SaveCopyAs FilePath
            ErrNumber = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    If ErrNumber = 0 Then ' a copy successfully saved

        Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
        FilePath = FileBasePath & ".xlsx"
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next
                dwb.SaveAs FilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        Kill FileBasePath & OldFileExtension
        
        If ErrNumber = 0 Then ' successfully coverted to '.xlsx'
            Set RefWorkbookConvertedToXLSX = dwb
        Else ' failed to save as '.xlsx'
            If ShowMessages Then
                MsgBox "Cannot save as """ & FilePath & """!", vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    
    Else ' an error occurred while saving a copy
        
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Cannot save as """ & FilePath & """!", vbExclamation
        End If
    
    End If

End Function


This seems way out of my depth. I got an error permission denied 70
